# Tutorial on how to create a flowing thread

Tags: adobe-photoshop, gimp, tutorial, patterns, inkscape

I'm looking for a tutorial to create wavy flowing threads. Like this:

[image: Sample]

I'm open to tutorials in Photoshop, GIMP, or any freeware image manipulation program. We have a copy of PS. I'm not sure if another graphic app is in the budget.

Comment: I'd use Inkscape's calligraphy tool, if I were you. It's *way* easier, and more powerful than anything you'd get with GIMP/Photoshop.

Comment: Is Illustrator not an option? Because it seems to be much easier there...

Comment: Spend some time on Veerle's site. She has lots of tutorials in this vein: veerle.duoh.com

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I'd use [Inkscape](http://inkscape.org/)'s calligraphy tool to draw the curve, if I were you. It's way easier, and more powerful than anything you'd get with GIMP/Photoshop.

---

If you *really* have to use GIMP:

You can use curves (somewhere in the toolbox). Draw a curve (preferably without anti-aliasing). Make the thickness something large enough. Now, select the curve using the Magic Wand/Floodfill tool (possibly by selecting the background, then inverting selection?). Next, use a gradient (not sure where it is - I use Paint.NET mostly), and overwrite the curve with your gradient. Later, you can add highlights using more layers (create layer, same process, but make the gradients smaller.

---

**EDIT:** A little [tutorial](https://imgur.com/a/Ti1i9#sdSW0) I made, as requested. Be sure to read the captions for instructions!

Comment: Thank you for recommending Inkscape. I will use that instead of PS. However, I am still looking for a good tutorial on how to create that effect.

Comment: @Levu WebWorks Added a [tutorial](http://imgur.com/a/Ti1i9#sdSW0). Hope it helps. :) Remember, you can export Inkscape files of ANY resolution/size (which is why vector graphics rock) to PNG/etc using `File->Export Bitmap`.

Comment: what about embedding the tutorial here?